# How to set default database in Postgresql database dump script?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'd need to initialize postgres instance to Docker container from dump SQL-file. Otherwise it works fine but the problem is I cannot set database to be something else than "postgres". Creating new database works fine but schema clauses eg. `CREATE TABLE` end up going nowhere.

I tried to set default database with `--env` option in `docker run` command but it returns error `--env requires a value`.

Is there any way to set default database? Hopefully in SQL-clause.

Comment: `set PGDATABASE=...`  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Comment: -> `unrecognized configuration parameter "pgdatabase"` @a_horse_with_no_name I quess some further config would be needed.

Comment: That's an operating system environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need to use `/connect "dbname=[database name]"` before schema clauses in order to point script towards correct dabase.

This wasn't (quite understandbly) included into the script when dump was generated only for a single database instead of the whole cluster.